# google chrome not running on 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

```
OS:4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

when I type google-chrome, it shows an error 
`[14033:14033:0604/061453:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(271)]` Gtk: cannot open display:

I have installed chrome browser with below command

```
sudo yum -y install google-chrome-stable –skip-broken
```

Hence even when I run my selenium test ,it shows as

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
   [testng]   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.2,platform=Linux 4.4.10-22.54.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
   [testng] Command duration or timeout: 21.07 seconds
```

Any one has any idea,what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't resolve this problem, any luck here ? I tried Xvfb setting `export DISPLAY=:1` and `Xvfb :1 screen 1024x768x240 +expression RANDR &`... Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Gtk+ dependencies needs to be installed as well.
Follow this blogpost to resolve that.
https://gist.github.com/joekiller/4144838

And also this:
http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.com/2013/02/setting-up-chrome-firefox-ec2-selenium-java.html

Solved: Try these step by step
`yum install libgcrypt-devel`
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/libstdc++-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm`
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/libstdc++-devel-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm`
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/cpp-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm`
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/gcc-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm`
`wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/15/x86_64/gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpmsudo rpm -Uvh libstdc++-devel-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm cpp-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm gcc-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm gcc-c++-4.6.3-2.fc15.x86_64.rpm`

`sudo yum remove google-chrome`
`wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm`
`sudo yum install ./google-chrome-stable_current_*.rpm`
`google-chrome &`

Now finally start your selenium tests.